# Truncar valor inteiro PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso chegar no seguinte resultado:

```
4,2 = 5
85,02 = 9
256,9 = 3...
```

Por enquanto, usei o código:

```
$novoservico = '402,02';
$novoservico = str_replace(",",".",$novoservico);
$valor_redondo = ceil($novoservico);
echo $valor_redondo; ?>
```

Com esse código, eu consigo arredondar os números sempre pra cima:

```
4,2 = 5
85,02 = 86
256,9 = 257...
```

No caso, eu preciso fazer com que esses números sejam "truncados pra cima". Não sei se fui muito claro usando essa expressão. Mas foi a melhor maneira de explicar o que eu preciso fazer.
Agradeço desde já. sobre qualquer observação ou duvida sobre a pergunta, estou a disposição.

Comment: 85,02 = 9? Isso não é arredondamento.

Comment: @DavidAlves tem razão, o sistema arredonda para o inteiro mais proximo

Comment: O resultado que você obteve é exatamente o resultado que você descreveu que quer obter, então a pergunta não fez sentido.

Comment: "porém ele só arredonda números após a virgula" - Esse é o conceito de arredondamento.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ele disse querer 85 virar 9, imagino que ele queira apenas números inteiros de 1 dígito. Mas não ficou claro

Comment: Isso faz menos sentido ainda. Votei para fechar como não clara até ter mais informações.

Comment: Eu sou um USUÁRIO tentando programar. Vocês deviam ter um senso critico um pouco mais apurado.
Tenho certeza que vocês entenderam o que eu quis dizer. Custa tentar me ajudar? Isso aqui é um fórum voltado pra iniciantes e profissionais. 
Eu estou começando no Stack Overflow. Ser "recebido" dessa forma não é nada agradável.
Eu agradeço pela ajuda Wees.
Eu não quero ser chato, só fique chateado com os comentários. Acho que um fórum serve pra ajudar

Comment: @RaulGermano e todos estão tentando te ajudar, se entendeu errado, não é culpa nossa. Sua pergunta não fez sentido, tanto que **todos** os que leram ficaram em dúvida. Se você é usuário ou desenvolvedor, iniciante ou avançado, pouco importa, mas a sua pergunta não está clara e demanda mais detalhes. Você foi questionado sobre o que quer fazer e não respondeu, então como quer ser ajudado assim? Na pergunta você diz que precisa de arredondamento para o inteiro acima e seu código faz **exatamente** isso. Se quer algo diferente, edite ([edit]) sua pergunta e descreva melhor o problema.

Comment: Vamos recomeçar. Acabei de editar

Comment: Então recomeçando, voltamos a pergunta: você precisa que o resultado seja **sempre** apenas um dígito, independente da grandeza da entrada? Se eu entrar com 10000000, deve retornar 1, enquanto eu entrar com 10000001 deve retornar 2?

Comment: Só para ficar claro [isto não é um forum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum) e todo o mundo está tentando ajudar. "Tenho certeza que vocês entenderam o que eu quis dizer" - Certamente que não, e vê isso pela quantidade de perguntas feitas no comentários (eu próprio não percebi bem o resultado que você procura exatamente). O que pode ser evidente para si que está dentro do contexto, nem sempre é para outros que não estão no mesmo contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se vc quer um número de 1 digito apenas, pode fazer assim:

```
$novoservico = '402,02';
$valor_redondo = $novoservico[0]+1;
echo $valor_redondo;
```

Ele vai imprimir sempre o próximo número, mas se for `int` realmente:

```
$valor_redondo = intval($novoservico[0]+1);
```

Comment: Sim. Porém ele irá subir um. Se eu por 100 ele vai pra 2, em vez de converter pra 1

Comment: se for 100 fica o 1 e se for 9?